# Generate Random no between x and y whose sum is m

Tags: android, random, logic

I want to generate n no of random no whose sum should be m and these no should always be between x and y.

For eg :- If i say I need 20 no, between 3 and 9 inclusive, whose sum should be 100.

I want to specify the sum and required amount of no as well as the limit between which random no should be generated and it should give me the random no of specified amount. Below is my code which do generates no which are greater than 2 but i am not able to put the max limit. Also, the sum which comes out and the sum of no. which it generates is not equal to specified sum. I am totally confused Please help me out.

```
TextView textView,randomTotaltxt;
int count0 = 0;
int count1 = 0;
int targetSum = 100;
int numberofDraws = 20;

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    randomTotaltxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomTptalText);

    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> load = new ArrayList<>();

    //random no
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numberofDraws;i++){
        int next = r.nextInt(targetSum)+1;
        Log.d("No",""+next);
        load.add(next);
        sum += next;
    }

    //scale it
    double scale = 1d*targetSum/sum;
    sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<numberofDraws;i++){
        load.set(i, (int)(load.get(i)*scale));
        sum += load.get(i);
    }

   while (load.contains(0)|| load.contains(1)){
       for (int i=0; i<load.size();i++) {
           if (load.get(i).equals(0)) {
               load.set(i, load.get(i) + 2);
               count0++;
               sum = sum+1;
           }
           if (load.get(i).equals(1)) {
               load.set(i, load.get(i) + 2);
               sum += load.get(i);
               count1++;
              sum = sum+1;
           }
       }
   }

    // take rounding
    while (sum++ <targetSum){
        int i = r.nextInt(numberofDraws);
        load.set(i, load.get(i) + 1);
    }

    textView.setText(""+load);
    randomTotaltxt.setText(""+(sum-1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the optimal solution but this will do your work as required.

```
int targetSum = 100;
int numberOfDraws = 20;
int uppr=0;
int countt =0;
ArrayList<Integer> load = new ArrayList<>();
Random random;
TextView textView1,randomTotaltxt1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    randomTotaltxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomTptalText1);

    random = new Random();

    //random no
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfDraws;i++){
        int next = random.nextInt(targetSum)+1;
        load.add(next);
        sum += next;
    }

    //scale it
    double scale = 1d*targetSum/sum;
    sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfDraws;i++){
        load.set(i, (int)(load.get(i)*scale));
        sum += load.get(i);
    }

    // take rounding
    while (sum++ <targetSum){
        int i = random.nextInt(numberOfDraws);
        load.set(i, load.get(i) + 1);
        Log.d("TAG",""+load);
    }

    checkForUpperRange();
}

public void checkForUpperRange(){
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfDraws;i++){
        int n = load.get(i);

        if (n > 9){
            load.set(i, 9);
            uppr = n - 9;   // getting the required no.
            adjustUpper();
            break;
        }

        checkForLowerRange();
    }
}

private void adjustUpper() {
    for (int j=0; j<numberOfDraws;j++){
        if (load.get(j) > 2){
            load.set(j, load.get(j)+uppr);    // uppr is added
            checkForUpperRange();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void checkForLowerRange(){
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfDraws;i++){
        int n = load.get(i);

        if (n == 0){
            load.set(i, load.get(i)+3); // 3 is added in sum
            adjust0();
            break;
        }

        if (n == 1){
            load.set(i, load.get(i)+2); // 2 is added in sum
            adjust1();
            break;
        }

        if (n == 2){
            load.set(i, load.get(i)+1); // 1 is added in sum
            adjust2();
            break;
        }

        getCount();
    }
}

public void getCount(){
    countt = 0;
    for (int k=0; k<numberOfDraws;k++){
        countt = countt+ load.get(k);
        showResult();
    }
}

public void showResult(){
    textView1.setText(""+load);
    randomTotaltxt1.setText(""+countt);
}

public void adjust0(){
    for (int j=0; j<numberOfDraws;j++){
        if (load.get(j) > 3){
            load.set(j, load.get(j)-3);    // 3 is subtracted
            checkForLowerRange();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void adjust1(){
    for (int j=0; j<numberOfDraws;j++){
        if (load.get(j) > 3){
            load.set(j, load.get(j)-2);    // 2 is subtracted
            checkForLowerRange();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void adjust2(){
    for (int j=0; j<numberOfDraws;j++){
        if (load.get(j) > 3){
            load.set(j, load.get(j)-1);    // 1 is subtracted
            checkForLowerRange();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```